# atualizar atributo mysql de acordo com um dia (12/12/2019) cakephp, mysql

Tags: mysql, mysqli, cakephp, cakephp-2, cakephp-3

Estou com o seguinte problema:

Caso um cliente não pague uma determinada parcela gostaria que o sistema (mysql+cakephp) colocasse o cliente com o status devedor. teria alguma forma de automatizar isso, sem que o funcionário altere manualmente o status do cliente?

Gostaria que o proprio mysql diariamente fizesse uma consulta no banco e trocasse o status dos clientes que não pagaram até aquele determinado dia para (atrasado) ai quando o funcionario entrasse no sistema ja viria os clientes que estão em atraso. a parte da aplicação é tranquilo pra mim a minha duvida é como que faço para automatizar essa logica do banco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode criar um evento.

Um evento é uma tarefa executada com base em um agendamento predefinido, portanto, às vezes, é referido como um evento agendado.

Um procedimento é executado apenas quando é chamado diretamente, um gatilho é executado quando ocorre um evento associado a uma tabela, como um evento de inserção, atualização ou exclusão. Já um evento pode ser executado em intervalos temporais regulares, uma ou mais vezes. O evento também é conhecido como "gatilho temporal" porque é acionado pelo tempo.

Um evento é semelhante a uma atividade cron no UNIX ou a um agendador de tarefas no Windows.

Você pode usar eventos em muitos casos, como otimizar tabelas de banco de dados, limpar logs, arquivar dados ou gerar relatórios complexos fora do horário de pico.

## Iniciando o agendador de eventos no MySQL.

Por padrão, o agendador de eventos não está ativado. Para habilitar e iniciar o agendamento de eventos, é necessário executar o seguinte comando:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

Para desativar o agendador de eventos execute o comando:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = OFF;
```

## Criando novos eventos MySQL

A criação de um evento é semelhante à criação de outros objetos de banco de dados, como procedimentos ou gatilhos.

Um evento é um objeto nomeado que contém instruções SQL.

## Syntaxe.

```
CREATE
    [DEFINER = user]
    EVENT
    [IF NOT EXISTS]
    nome_do_evento
    ON SCHEDULE schedule
    [ON COMPLETION [NOT] PRESERVE]
    [ENABLE | DISABLE | DISABLE ON SLAVE]
    [COMMENT 'string']
    DO corpo_do_event;

schedule:
    AT timestamp [+ INTERVAL intervalo] ...
  | EVERY intervalo
    [STARTS timestamp [+ INTERVAL intervalo] ...]
    [ENDS timestamp [+ INTERVAL intervalo] ...]

intervalo:
    quantity {YEAR | QUARTER | MONTH | DAY | HOUR | MINUTE |
              WEEK | SECOND | YEAR_MONTH | DAY_HOUR | DAY_MINUTE |
              DAY_SECOND | HOUR_MINUTE | HOUR_SECOND | MINUTE_SECOND}
```

`CREATE EVENT` requer o privilégio `EVENT` para o esquema no qual o evento deve ser criado.

A cláusula `ON SCHEDULE` determina quando e  com que frequência e por quanto tempo a ação definida em  corpo_do_event definido se repete. Esta cláusula assume uma das duas formas:

- `AT timestamp` que é usado para um evento único. Ele especifica que o evento
  é executado apenas uma vez na data e hora fornecidas por timestamp ou deve ser uma expressão que seja resolvida para um valor de data e hora. Você pode usar um valor do tipo `DATETIME` ou `TIMESTAMP`para esse propósito.
- `EVERY` que é usado para repetir ações em um intervalo regular. A cláusula `EVERY` pode conter uma cláusula `STARTS seguida por um timestamp que indica quando a ação deve começar a se repetir.Também pode conter uma cláusula ENDS seguida por um timestamp que informa ao MySQL quando o evento deve parar de se repetir.

Os requisitos mínimos para realizar uma declaração `CREATE EVENT` válida são os seguintes:

- As palavras-chave `CREATE EVENT` mais um nome único de evento, que
  identifica exclusivamente o evento em um esquema de banco de dados.
- Uma cláusula `ON SCHEDULE` que determina quando e com que frequência
  o evento é executado.
- Uma cláusula `DO` que contém a instrução SQL a ser executada pelo
  evento.

Para descartar o evento use a declaração `DROP EVENT`:

```
DROP EVENT [IF EXISTS] nome_do_evento
```

*Para mais detalhes sobre a sintaxe de `CREATE EVENT` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-event.html*

*Para mais detalhes sobre a sintaxe de `DROP EVENT`

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/drop-event.html*

## Resposta

Aplicando a sua questão o que posso oferecer é um exemplo superficial de um evento que todos os dias verifica a tabela de clientes e se o pagamento é 0 ele muda o status do cliente para devedor, pois não foram apresentados dados específicos sobre o formato dos dados em sua pergunta:

```
CREATE EVENT verificarEstatus
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY DAY STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    DO
      UPDATE alugueis.clientes SET status = "DEVEDOR" WHERE pagamento = 0;
```

Esse evento inicia a verificação no dia 12/12/2019:

```
CREATE EVENT verificarEstatus
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY DAY STARTS TIMESTAMP('2019-12-12')
    DO
      UPDATE alugueis.clientes SET status = "DEVEDOR" WHERE pagamento = 0;
```

Esse evento inicializa hoje a verificação e termina no dia 12/12/2019:

```
CREATE EVENT verificarEstatus
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY DAY STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
                ENDS TIMESTAMP('2019-12-12')
    DO
      UPDATE alugueis.clientes SET status = "DEVEDOR" WHERE pagamento = 0;
```

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado meu querido, super ajudou!